# Can you identify this aircraft photographed during solar eclipse 8/21/2017?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

The following sequence of shots was taken about 9.5 minutes before the start of the eclipse, 1:12pm EST.

Shooting in burst mode off of a tripod - all 3 shots taken within 1 second. Burst mode is 14 frames per second, so it's reasonable to assume that these 3 photos were taken 1/14sec apart.

**Exif:** 
Camera: Canon EOS1DX
Lens: Sigma 150-600mm Contemporary.
1/8000s, f/29, ISO 100, focal length 600mm. No filter.
[image]

- First image: the aircraft is seen above the sun - no contrails.
- Second image: completely different trajectory and a contrail (?)
- 3rd image: the aircraft is gone.

**Zoomed in:**

[image]

Comment: About the trajectory: the wind is probably moving left to right.

Comment: The contrails in the second image are missing in the first. Contrails can't appear behind an aircraft retroactively like that. In the second image they are right up against the aircraft. These images likely do not show the same aircraft.

Comment: Where in the US was that photographed?

Comment: Perhaps if you can give exact time and location [FlightRadar24](https://www.flightradar24.com/) could be used to identify the aircraft.

Comment: If I've measured the pixels correctly, this object travelled about 26 times its own length between the two frames.  If the frames are only 1/14 of a second apart, this is bloody fast;  for comparison, an SR-71 blackbird travels about 2.2 times its body length in the same amount of time (assuming a speed of 2200 mph.)  Hell, the Space Shuttle "only" travelled about 10 times its own length during re-entry.  Either the time between the frames is much different than 1/14 second, or this isn't an aircraft.

Comment: (the Space Shuttle "only" travelled about 10 times its own length *in 1/14 second* during re-entry)

Comment: @gamecatcher Were these three the only ones taken in the one second, or were there fourteen? the fewer frames that are taken, the longer the intervals should be. that would effect the speed calculations hugely.

Comment: Even with 1 second between every shot, the contrail of that length wouldn't appear and then vanish in one second - let alone 1/14 of a second. This has every indication of being a complete waste of everyone's time & attention, either a technical glitch in the camera or a hoax.  (NO FILTER??? And the camera wasn't fried? Bet there was SOME filter involved!)  And in every case, entirely off-topic at Av.SE. This thread needs to be moved to skeptics.se or deleted in its entirety!

Comment: No filter?  How did you not fry the sensor in that camera shooting straight at the sun?

Comment: Why was the "military" tag applied to this thread?  Doesn't that pre-suppose that the answer to the question has to be a military aircraft?

Comment: Why was no location for the photos mentioned in the post?  Wouldn't a person seeking answers want to provide that sort of information in order to help those who'd be interested in answering?

Comment: @Notts90 It looks delta-winged, which would make it military. Military planes usually aren't on tracking websites.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the second picture and the list of US military jet, I would guess F-22 Raptor, and since this kind of aircraft usually fly by 2, the jet in the first picture is maybe a second F-22.

[image: F-22]

As for the timing of the shots, the trail we see in the second pic not appearing in the 3rd is telling me they were shot with at least a couple of seconds interval. That would also explain why each jet appears only in one pic.

Comment: " is telling me they were shot with at least a couple of seconds interval" but the timestamp is the same for each photo, suggesting, as the OP said in the question, that they were shot within a much smalle timeframe

Answer (score -1):

The first plane that came into my head after seeing these pictures was the F-117 Nighthawk:

[image: F-117 Nighthawk]

**However**, this object pictured could easily be something else (maybe not even a plane) due to the low quality of the object and its speed, so no answer will be 100% accurate.

Comment: I was under the impression the Nighthawk fleet had been retired years ago. Are there any still flying?

Comment: Yes I was thinking the same whilst I was writing the answer. However they may still have a few left over. But I have no idea if they would fly them.

Comment: Nvm I found this website explaining why we might still see them in the skies. http://intercepts.defensenews.com/2014/11/we-now-know-why-the-f-117-is-still-flying/

Comment: @Mark That article is from 2014. Plus, the shape of the image doesn't have two distinct wing tips, but instead has a singular surface, more like that of the X-32, but even then, it's not similar enough. I doubt it's either one. https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/0e/2d/a7/0e2da7402ec1f2275de092cd66af47c0--youth-fighter-jets.jpg That, plus the contrails suddenly appearing where they were not in earlier images, makes this collage seem very fake.

Comment: At the level of detail shown in the photographs, it could be pretty much any delta-winged aircraft. It seems much more likely to be something in current inventory.